# React e Leaflet: Jest encountered an unexpected token

Tags: javascript, react, testes, jest, leaflet

Estou tentando criar testes com jest para um projeto de vaga de estágio, mas fica dando erro por causa da lib de mapa que instalei (leaflet). o erro é esse aqui:

Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
For information about custom transformations, see:
https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

Details:

/home/vinicius/Documents/react/teste-frontend-estagio-v2/node_modules/react-leaflet/lib/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export { useMap, useMapEvent, useMapEvents } from './hooks.js';
                                                                                  ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

  1 | /* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
  2 | import React from 'react'
> 3 | import { MapContainer, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet'
    | ^
  4 | import './styles.css'
  5 |
  6 | export default function Map ({ content, zoom }) {

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Map/index.js:3:1)
```

Quando removo a linha 3, os testes funcionam normalmente.

Comment: É difícil dizer sem ver as configurações do seu projeto. O que dá para o adiantar é que seu código não foi transpilado antes do teste e o *Jest* não sabe o que fazer com a palavra-chave `export`.

Comment: meu jest.config: `export default {transform: {}}`. Se tiver algum arquivo específico que possa ajudar, pode me falar.

Answer (score 0):

Passando pra dar uma atualização: fiquei pesquisando como resolver e testei algumas configurações no jest.config. Nada funcionava, então eu mudei e configurei no package.json até que os testes passaram. a solução foi adicionar isso no package.json:

```
"jest": {
 "transformIgnorePatterns": [
   "/node_modules/(?!(react-leaflet/lib|@react-leaflet/core/lib)/)"
 ]
```

},